# Xcode 4 Set Next Statement, QuickWatch, Bookmarks,

Tags: xcode, debugging

any idea where can I find these great debugging features? I settle with bookmarks, but what about the others?

Set Next Statement
QuickWatch
ImmediateWindow
CallersGraph

Sry, i'm pretty new in xcode and mac dev.
Thnx

Answer (score 2):

Set Next Statement - just drag the instruction pointer (from [this post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Sep/msg00298.html)).

Have you found the "Debug Area" (View -> Debug Area)? There you can interact with the command-line debugger (e.g. gbd) via the Output pane, which is somewhat like the Immediate pane in MSVS if I remember correctly. There's also the variables pane.

I'm not sure what you call the CallersGraph, you should be more specific (at least link to the appropriate MSVS help pages).